# Vuejs if image exists

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to vuejs, i have a mounted section to search for an image:

```
mounted () {
    this.UserImage = localStorage.Image
    this.UserName  = localStorage.Name      
},
```

When i have no image `this.UserImage` returns the string: `data:image/jpeg;base64,`

What can i use to compare and using v-if v-else display some default image in case i did not found an image ?

My try was :

```
mounted () {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.UserImage = localStorage.Image
        this.UserName  = localStorage.Name
    })
  },
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you know that it'll be that exact string then use an `if` satement, compare to that string and it's true then set a different image url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have done something like this :

```js
mounted () {
    this.UserImage = localStorage.Image !== 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' ? localStorage.Image : defaultPath
},
```

It'd help keeping the template clean.

I would set the image that doesn't exist to an empty string (instead of `data:image/jpeg;base64,`). That way you could have a shorter implicit if statement :

```js
mounted () {
    this.UserImage = localStorage.Image || defaultPath
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<img :src="userImage" v-if="userImage !== 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'">
<img src="defaultImagePath" v-else>
```